# jQuery UI drag/drop sorting comparision using float:left vs display:inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two examples here,
only difference between these two example are
one uses display:inline-block and other one uses float:left,

li.doc_item{display:inline-block;}
 vs 
li.doc_item{float:left;}

My problem is display:inline-block sorting is not as fast or responsive as float:left.
I want to use display:inline-block because thumbnails that I am re-ordering 
sometimes can vary in size and float:left doesn't work well when thumbnails have different height and width.

Any question is how to make block:inline-block as fast as float:left ?

You can find comparative example here:
http://dev-server-2.com/drag-drop-sample/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same issue, and figured I should find out what's causing it.

It's because they treat floated elements differently, and that differentiation should be made on inline-block as well.

Try this patch:

```
jQuery.ui.sortable.prototype._create = function() {
    var o = this.options;
    this.containerCache = {};
    this.element.addClass("ui-sortable");

    //Get the items
    this.refresh();

    //Let's determine if the items are floating, treat inline-block as floating as well
    this.floating = this.items.length ? (/left|right/).test(this.items[0].item.css('float')) || this.items[0].item.css('display') == 'inline-block' : false;

    //Let's determine the parent's offset
    this.offset = this.element.offset();

    //Initialize mouse events for interaction
    this._mouseInit();
};
```

it's especially this row:

```
this.floating = this.items.length ? (/left|right/).test(this.items[0].item.css('float')) || this.items[0].item.css('display') == 'inline-block' : false;
```

That changes the default behaviour. This is a late answer, but I couldn't find any other answer around the net so I thought this would help a lot of people.

I will try to submit a patch-request for jQuery that fixes this, but as of 1.8.9 this is still a problem.

Comment: WOW you are a genius, after using your patch display:inline-block's drag/drop working as fast as that of float:left
Thanks for posting it, really appreciate it lot. cheers mate!

Comment: Glad I could help. Keep an eye on this ticket: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6942 to find out when they fix it in the source.

Comment: Found somewhat similar issue, http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8872. Solved it by adding float to .ui-draggable-dragging

Comment: They claim to have fixed this in jQuery UI 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a fixed-sized container with `float:left;` and `text-align:center;` for an image with `vertical-align:middle; max-height:100%; max-width:100%;`
Your images would be displayed as a mosaic whatever their dimensions.

I don't know if it's possible in your case ?

Comment: fixed-size container hummm something like this.

li.doc_item {
float:left;
width:250px;
height:250px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer;
}

li is my container for imgs, this might work for me... let me give it a try, thanx