# jQueryUI sortable floating items in connected lists height issue and flickering WON'T WORK

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two connected lists, #gallery and #trash. When you drag the items around in the #gallery, its smooth and no flickering.

I want to be able to drag from #trash to gallery. However it does not let you do this. You have to drag the item to the top of the #gallery then it becomes active again and then allows you to drag the item around.

This happens because of the ul having a height of 0 when float: left is enabled on all of its child elements. Adding overflow: hidden to the ul will fix this but will reintroduce the flickering.

No matter what I try i cant seem to get the two working together. I want to be able to drag from #gallery to #trash and drag around in each div individually with NO flickering.

I have a full demo below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/67/

As you will see you cant drag up from #tash to #gallery unless you drag it to the very top of #gallery.

I have tried changing the float left to inline-block = This works.... but the flickering coems back so no success.

```
#gallery li{display: inline-block;}
#trash li{display: inline-block;}
```

Also tried giving the ul a height but it introduces the flickering again!

I have been told of the clearfix solution. Solution is to add clearfix on ul ( I.E. with :after and :before) but what i have tried didnt work (unless im doing it wrong.)

```
#gallery:after { clear:both; content:'.'; display:block; height:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; visibility:hidden; padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Also found this, but not sure if this would help:

```
activate: function(en, ui) {
   // do something here, height, float, inline, overflow etc?
       },
deactivate: function(en, ui) {
      // then do something here
    },
```

Any help would be REALLY appreciated. Hope someone can put me out of my pain with this! I have tired everything i can think of.

Cheers

Comment: Your `ul` is only `10px` tall and so is not being entered. Try giving it a fixed height based on the containing div using jquery.

Comment: Thats what the problem is, as soon as i had a height, ie float: left;
height: auto; the flickering becomes really bad when moving items around. The min-height is a hack to fix the issue when the container is empty you cant drag items into it.

Comment: Have you tried using jquery to adjust a fixed height whenever an element is added or taken away? When I gave it a fixed height it fixed the flickering, but obviously you need some way of making it dynamic. Possibly keep track of the containing divs height and when it grows/shrinks, grow/shrink your `ul`.

Comment: I give up lol cant be fixed. Nothing works

Comment: It's definitely possible, I'll have a go, give me a bit.

Comment: Cheers :-) not sure if this is the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879219/jquery-ui-drag-drop-sorting-comparision-using-floatleft-vs-displayinline-block

Comment: Hi, any luck? I kind of willing to give away all the points i have to get this sorted!

Comment: Sorry was busy yesterday, I'm almost there I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the changes I made: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/68/

```
var galleryHeight;
var selectedLis;
var timer;

function checkChanges(){
    var tempHeight;
    if(selectedLis != $("#gallery li").length)
    {
        selectedLis = $("#gallery li").length;
        $('#gallery').css('height', 10 + 'px');
        galleryHeight = $('#selectedContainer').css("height");      
        console.log(galleryHeight);
        tempHeight = parseInt(galleryHeight) - 49; 
        $('#gallery').css('height', tempHeight + 'px');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    galleryHeight = $('#selectedContainer').css("height");
    selectedLis = $("#gallery li").length;
    timer = setInterval(checkChanges,5000);
});
```

Basically I'm just updating the height of the ul every time the list gets bigger or smaller. 5000ms might be a bit long of a wait, it can be reduced. Hopefully this is what you wanted, I'm not sure if it works properly on jsfiddle as I was only testing it offline.

### Update:

I put in a delay, seems to have smoothed it out quite a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/69/

```
//Connect the two lists enable dragging between each one
$("#gallery").sortable({
    revert: true,
    connectWith: "#trash",
    refreshPositions: true,

    // Newly added to change container background
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $("li.ui-state-highlight").text("place here").delay(1500); //delay here seems to smooth out the movement
        $(".containerTwo").stop().animate({"background-color":"#ffb9b9", "border-color":"#f06666", "border-top-style":"dashed", "border-right-style":"dashed", "border-bottom-style":"dashed", "border-left-style":"dashed",  "border-width":"1px"}, 50);
    }, 
    stop: function(event, ui) {
         $(".containerTwo").stop().animate({"background-color":"#fff", "border-color":"#aaa", "border-top-style":"solid", "border-right-style":"solid", "border-bottom-style":"solid", "border-left-style":"solid",  "border-width":"1px"}, 50);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it. Seems to solve the issue of not being able to drag in unless you go to the top. But it re introduces the flickering again. Like it most of the stuff i have tired I get one think fixed, then the other thing breaks.

Comment: Check my edit, see if that solves it. Looks a lot smoother to me anyway.

Comment: @gaynorvader still there is flickering